# Empty list after applying a filter

Tags: powershell

I can't get a filter to work with powershell
I don't understand where I'm wrong

```
 Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxxx.it" -Name "@" -RRType "txt"
```

```
HostName                  RecordType Type       Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData                                        
--------                  ---------- ----       ---------            ----------      ----------                                        
@                         TXT        16         0                    04:00:00        v=spf1 mx a include:xxxx.it ?all               
@                         TXT        16         0                    04:00:00        google-site-verification=xxxxxx...
_dmarc                    TXT        16         0                    04:00:00        v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:dmarc.rua@ma...
```

if I try to apply a filter

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxxxx.it" -Name "@" -RRType "txt" |
  Where-Object RecordData -Like v*
```

I get an empty list.
Where is the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: The .RecordData field is probably it's own object class, instead of a string.  To check this out, run this command.  ` Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxxx.it" -Name "@" -RRType "txt"  | select -expand RecordData".  You will likely see multiple columns returned.  Once you do, just index into the field you want, like this.  ` Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxxx.it" -Name "@" -RRType "txt"  | Where $_.RecordData.WhateverField -like "v*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by myself
Here is the solution

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "xxxx.it" -RRType "txt" |
  Where-Object {$_.RecordData.DescriptiveText -like 'v=spf1*'}
```

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to accept you own answer by clicking the checkmark on the left (once the timer runs out) :-)